# The application doesn't start after the self-update installation is completed

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

There was such a problem. I add an app self-update. The ".apk" is downloaded and I run the application installer via File Provider and Intent.

```
Intent intent;
Uri apkUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(mContext, mContext.getPackageName() + ".fileprovider", file);
intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(apkUri);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
mContext.startActivity(intent);
```

Everything works fine, the application is installed.

[Package installer window screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zUS2J.png)

But where i try to start app by "Open" button in Package Installer window, nothing happens.

But there is a message in Logcat about the start of the activity.

> START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 pkg=com.example.myapp cmp=com.example.myapp/.MainActivity} from uid 10067

Also, then an Exception from packageinstaller appears in the logcat:

> Failed to note usage stop
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to stop usage for com.android.packageinstaller, not in use
> at com.android.server.usage.AppTimeLimitController.noteUsageStop(AppTimeLimitController.java:955)
> at com.android.server.usage.UsageStatsService.reportEvent(UsageStatsService.java:918)
> at com.android.server.usage.UsageStatsService$H.handleMessage(UsageStatsService.java:1364)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
> at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)

By the shortcut everything starts without any problem.
Also all works on Android 7,8 Emulator and Devices.

This problem occurs on Android 11 and 12 both on the emulator and the device.

Activity manifest:

```
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.myApp.NoActionBar"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|stateHidden">
        <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
             <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
         </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```